# Determine the number of integer solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 < 40$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Determine the number of integer solutions for $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5 < 40$

a) $x_i \geq 0, i = 1,2,\dots,5$.

b) $x_i \geq -3, i = 1,2,\dots,5$.

c) $-3 \leq x_i \leq 10, i = 1,2,\dots,5$.

My try is

a)$x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5+x_6=40$

${40+6-1 \choose 40}=1221759$

need help on b) and c)

Comment: For b, let $y_i=x_i+3$, and so $x_i=y_i-3$, so $\sum_i (y_i-3)=40$, so $\sum_i y_i= 40+18$ where $y_i \geq 0$ and now you've reduced the problem to the type of part a.

Comment: Be careful.  In part (a), since $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ are non-negative integers whose sum is less than $40$, $x_6 \geq 1$.  Let $y_6 = x_6 - 1$.  Then $y_6$ is a non-negative integer.  If we substitute $y_6 + 1$ for $x_6$ in the equation $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 40$$ we obtain $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + y_6 = 39$$ which is an equation in the non-negative integers with $\binom{39 + 5}{5} = \binom{44}{5}$ solutions in the non-negative integers.

Answer (score 3):

For the first problem, observe that if $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ are non-negative integers satisfying the inequality 
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 < 40 \tag{1}$$
then $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 \leq 39$.  Let $x_6 = 39 - (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)$.  Then $x_6$ is a non-negative integer. Moreover, the number of solutions of inequality 1 in the non-negative integers is equal to the number of solutions to the equation
$$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5 + x_6 = 39 \tag{2}$$
in the non-negative integers.  A particular solution to equation 2 corresponds to a choice of where to insert five addition signs in a row of $39$ ones.   Hence, the number of solutions of equation 2 in the non-negative integers is $$\binom{39 + 5}{5} = \binom{44}{5}$$ since we must select which five of the $44$ symbols ($39$ ones and five addition signs) are addition signs.

For the second problem, let $y_k = x_k + 3$ for $1 \leq k \leq 5$.  Since each $x_k \geq -3$, each $y_k$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $y_k - 3$ for $x_k$, $1 \leq k \leq 5$ in inequality 1 yields
\begin{align*}
y_1 - 3 + y_2 - 3 + y_3 - 3 + y_4 - 3 + y_5 - 3 & < 40\\
y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_5 + y_5 & < 55 \tag{3}
\end{align*}
Then $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 \leq 54$.  Let $y_6 = 54 - (y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5)$.  Then $y_6$ is a non-negative integer.  The number of solutions of inequality 3 in the non-negative integers is equal to the number of solutions of the equation
$$y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 54 \tag{4}$$
in the non-negative integers.  The number of solutions of equation 4 in the non-negative integers is

> $$\binom{54 + 5}{5} = \binom{59}{5}$$

For the third problem, we must exclude those solutions of the second problem in which at least one of the variables $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ exceeds $10$.  Since $y_k = x_k + 3$ for $1 \leq k \leq 5$, this is equivalent to excluding those solutions of equation 4 in which one or more of the variables $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ exceeds $13$.  Since $4 \cdot 14 = 56 > 54$, at most three of the variables $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ can exceed $13$ simultaneously.

Suppose $y_1 > 13$.  Then $z_1 = y_1 - 14$ is a non-negative integer.  Substituting $z_1 + 14$ for $y_1$ in equation 4 yields 
$$z_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 40 \tag{5}$$
Equation 5 has

> $$\binom{40 + 5}{5} = \binom{45}{5}$$

solutions in the non-negative integers.  Since there are $\binom{5}{1}$ ways for one of the variables $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ to exceed $13$, the number of solutions of equation 4 in the non-negative integers in which one of the variables $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ exceeds $13$ is

> $$\binom{5}{1}\binom{45}{5}$$

Suppose $y_1, y_2 > 13$.  Let $z_1 = y_1 - 14$; let $y_2 = z_2 - 14$.  Then $z_1, z_2$ are non-negative integers.  Substituting $z_1 + 14$ for $y_1$ and $z_2 + 14$ for $y_2$ in equation 4 yields

$$z_1 + z_2 + y_3 + y_4 + y_5 + y_6 = 26 \tag{6}$$

Equation 6 is an equation with

> $$\binom{26 + 5}{5} = \binom{31}{5}$$

solutions in the non-negative integers.  Since there are $\binom{5}{2}$ ways for two of the variables $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ to exceed $13$, the number of solutions of equation 4 in the non-negative integers in which two of the variables $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ exceed $13$ is

> $$\binom{5}{2}\binom{31}{5}$$

By similar argument, the number of solutions of equation 4 in the non-negative integers in which three of the variables $y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4, y_5$ exceed $13$ is

> $$\binom{5}{3}\binom{12 + 5}{5} = \binom{5}{3}\binom{17}{5}$$

By the [Inclusion-Exclusion Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of solutions of the second problem in which $x_k \leq 10$ for $1 \leq k \leq 5$, is

> $$\binom{59}{5} - \binom{5}{1}\binom{45}{5} + \binom{5}{2}\binom{31}{5} - \binom{5}{3}\binom{17}{5}$$

Comment: What happened to the displays?

Comment: @MikeJones  When I scroll over the displays, the hidden expressions or equations are revealed.  What happens when you scroll over them?  I hid the expressions or equations since I wanted the person who posted the question to think about the answers rather than passively reading them.

Comment: Cool! I simply didn't know about that feature / technique.